# Editing biblatex to a particular style

Tags: biblatex, citing

This is the style that I am trying to achieve:

> Smith J, Jones M Jr, Houghton L et al (1999) Future of health insurance. N Engl J Med 965:325–329

I need two more changes that I am not able to figure out:

- remove comma after journal name
- remove and in author and force the order Last Name Initials for all authors

I provide my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[dashed=false,style=authoryear,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
     or
     test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
  }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{:#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}



\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Andeweg2011,
    title={Puzzles of Government Formation: Coalition Theory and Deviant Cases},
    author={Andeweg, Rudy W. and De Winter, Lieven and Dumont, Patrick},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{ansolabehere2005voting,
  title={Voting weights and formateur advantages in the formation of coalition governments},
  author={Ansolabehere, Stephen and Snyder Jr., James M. and Strauss, Aaron B. and Ting, Michael M.},
  journal={American Journal of Political Science},
  volume={49},
  number={3},
  pages={550--563},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}


\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
text
\textcite{Andeweg2011, ansolabehere2005voting}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please see [the editing help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to format questions. Please also note, that you are asking several questions in one. Most (or all) of them are already answered as single question or also as part of such multi-questions. So I would suggest to try a little more searching.

Comment: Please ask only about one issue per question. That makes your question easier to answer and more relevant for other people. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. Especially with bibliography styles, which can become very complex if you add many requirements, this approach is useful, because it enables people to pick and choose what they need.

Comment: Note that unless your `biblatex` is really old `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}` is more idiomatic than `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}`. `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{:#1}` is better dealt with as `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` and `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}`.

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` is outdated and should be `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}` now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these resources, I will look if I find solutions there. Also thanks for clarifications about the number of issues per question - I will take it into account. I will check the resources and see if I still have questions

Comment: Thanks for \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} and \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon} - it works!

Comment: For author the following worked: \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

Answer (score 1):

I post solution. Many thanks to everyone

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[dashed=false,style=authoryear,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
     test {\ifentrytype{article}}%
     or
     test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}%
  }{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
 \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}
 \renewrobustcmd*{\bibinithyphendelim}{}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Andeweg2011,
    title={Puzzles of Government Formation: Coalition Theory and Deviant Cases},
    author={Andeweg, Rudy W. and De Winter, Lieven and Dumont, Patrick},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{ansolabehere2005voting,
  title={Voting weights and formateur advantages in the formation of coalition governments},
  author={Ansolabehere, Stephen and Snyder Jr., James M. and Strauss, Aaron B. and Ting, Michael M.},
  journal={American Journal of Political Science},
  volume={49},
  number={3},
  pages={550--563},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}


\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
text
\textcite{Andeweg2011, ansolabehere2005voting}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```